# Iterating inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to iterator through a List, add the each element from the List to a new List and remove the element from the original list. I have three threads running the same process on the same original list.
Each thread needs to add 3 books and remove those 3 books each pass through the loop.

Here is my code:

```
    public class BookBoxer {  
  static List<Book> library = new ArrayList<>();

  static Librarian librarian1 = new Librarian();
  static Thread thread1 = new Thread(librarian1, "librarian1");

  static Librarian librarian2 = new Librarian();
  static Thread thread2 = new Thread(librarian2, "librarian2");

  static Librarian librarian3 = new Librarian();
  static Thread thread3 = new Thread(librarian3, "librarian3");


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    buldLibrary();

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    System.out.println("Librarian 1: total books: "+ librarian1.getTotalBooks()+ 
        " || total value: $" + librarian1.getTotalValue());
    System.out.println("librarian 1 book: " + librarian1.box.toString());
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Librarian 2: total books: "+ librarian2.getTotalBooks()+ 
        " || total value: $" + librarian2.getTotalValue());
    System.out.println("librarian 2 book: " + librarian2.box.toString());
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Librarian 3: total books: "+ librarian3.getTotalBooks()+ 
        " || total value: $" + librarian3.getTotalValue());
    System.out.println("librarian 3 book: " + librarian3.box.toString());
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("This is the new library " + library);

    System.out.println("The library has books: " + libraryHasBooks());
  }

  public static void buldLibrary() {
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 101) {
      Book book = new Book("Book #");
      library.add(book);
      book.incrementPrice();
      System.out.println(book.toString());
      i++;
    }
  }

  public static boolean libraryHasBooks() {
    if(library.isEmpty()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

static class Librarian implements Runnable {
     private static long sleepTime = ((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
     private double totalValue;
     private int totalBooks = 0;
     List<Book> box = new ArrayList<>();

    private void getBook(List<Book> aLibrary) { 
      Iterator<Book> libraryIterator = aLibrary.iterator();
        if(libraryIterator.hasNext()) {
        box.add(libraryIterator.next());
        }
    }  

    private void removeBook(List<Book> aLibrary) { 
      Iterator<Book> libraryIterator = aLibrary.iterator();
      if(libraryIterator.hasNext()) {
      libraryIterator.next();
      libraryIterator.remove();
      }
    }

    private double getTotalValue() {
      Iterator<Book> boxIterator = box.iterator();
        while(boxIterator.hasNext()) {
        totalValue += boxIterator.next().getPrice();
        }
        return totalValue;
      }

    private int getTotalBooks() {
      for(Book i : box) {
        totalBooks++;
      } 
      return totalBooks;
    }

    public void performAction() { 
     for(int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
       this.getBook(library);
       this.removeBook(library);
     }
   }

    @Override
    public void run() { 
      while(libraryHasBooks())
        {
          this.performAction();
          try 
          {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
      }

  }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
    Librarian 1: total books: 3 || total value: $3.75
librarian 1 book: [Name: Book #1 Price: $1.0, Name: Book #2 Price: $1.25, Name: Book #3 Price: $1.5]

Librarian 2: total books: 3 || total value: $6.0
librarian 2 book: [Name: Book #4 Price: $1.75, Name: Book #5 Price: $2.0, Name: Book #6 Price: $2.25]

Librarian 3: total books: 3 || total value: $8.25
librarian 3 book: [Name: Book #7 Price: $2.5, Name: Book #8 Price: $2.75, Name: Book #9 Price: $3.0]

This is the new library [Name: Book #10 Price: $3.25, Name: Book #11 Price: $3.5, Name: Book #12 Price: $3.75, Name: Book #13 Price: $4.0, Name: Book #14 Price: $4.25, Name: Book #15 Price: $4.5, Name: Book #16 Price: $4.75, Name: Book #17 Price: $5.0, Name: Book #18 Price: $5.25, Name: Book #19 Price: $5.5,....................

The library has books: true

Exception in thread "librarian3" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at com.github.salvadore_jefferson.libraryapp.BookBoxer$Librarian.getBook(BookBoxer.java:80)
    at com.github.salvadore_jefferson.libraryapp.BookBoxer$Librarian.performAction(BookBoxer.java:109)
    at com.github.salvadore_jefferson.libraryapp.BookBoxer$Librarian.run(BookBoxer.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html  try this instead of list . Or use guarded blocks or synchronized methods .

Comment: **You cannot do this with your approach**. You a) have no synchronisation on an `Collection` that is **not** threadsafe and b) have no control for your separate threads - what makes you think that they would take 3 books each? Your code is entirely wrong and not a lot is salvageable.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the LIbrarian class, this is difficult to diagnose precisely.  However, in the Java collections framework, creating an Iterator over a collection, and then modifying the collection over which the iterator iterates will cause this problem; once the collection has changed, the iterator is no longer valid (and will throw the concurrent modification exception if you try to use it).  The fact that you have multiple threads, presumably each with its own iterator, that are modifying the collection will cause this problem.

Comment: Bobby StJacques, the Librarian class is an inner class of BookBoxer. The code is included above.

Thanks for the assistance as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Concurrent Queue implementation that should do what you want (Your code as described seems to be dealing with it more as a queue than as a list).

If you must use a list (Well, a queue IS a list, but maybe you have special requirements), you will have to synchronize your methods which will make the the whole threading thing pointless--but if it's an exercise then maybe that's what they want to teach you...  IF that's the case, don't loop over the list (iterators will bust) and put a synchronized(list) around every section of code where you interact with the list.

Also be sure to put your read and remove inside the same synchronized statement--as you are coding think defensively.  Any hole where another thread could slip in and "Attack" you should be considered!  Even something like x++ can be messed up if it's in 2 threads and not properly protected.

Comment: Thanks for this Bill K!!

Answer (score 0):

it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. see [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: I am still very new to Java. I don't understand why this works for the first pass of the loop, and why it prints out the remaining books and then produces the error.

Also, I must not be understanding something, as the threads sleep for a time so it seems one would not modify the list while the other iterates over it?

Comment: @salvadore-jefferson: It looks like it's just a timing issue.  Since you are printing the output only once after starting the three threads, they have only had time to run once each.  The exception may not actually be thrown at the same place each time.

Comment: I got this application doing what its supposed to do with the help from some of the comments in here, thanks Biil K. Without having to scrap all the code as someone suggested.

It took some work but I pulled it off for at least a passing grade. Maybe an A+ :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do it in by synchronizing list.
2. you can wait on one common shared object.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would update this question with the changes I made to get this working. Here are the more significant code changes made:

```
static Queue<Book> library = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public static boolean libraryHasBooks() {
    if (library.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Closing Application");
      System.out.println("The Library has : " + library);
      librarian1.getResults();
      librarian2.getResults();
      librarian3.getResults();
      System.exit(0);
    }
    return true;
  }

private synchronized void removeBook() {
      Iterator<Book> libraryIterator = library.iterator();
      if (libraryIterator.hasNext()) {
        libraryIterator.next();
        library.poll();
      }
    }
public synchronized void performAction() {
      for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
        this.getBook();
        this.removeBook();
        this.getTotalValue();
        this.getTotalBooks();
      }
    }

public void getResults() {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(this.getName() + ": Has " + this.getTotalBooks() +" books. "  
     + " With a total value of $" + this.getTotalValue());
     System.out.println(this.getName() + ": Has " + this.box.toString());
    }

@Override
    public void run() {
      while(libraryHasBooks()) {
        this.performAction();
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }      
    }
```